# How to allow special characters in email validation?

Tags: android, validation

I am trying to allow special characters while validating user entered email but android standard utils.pattern validation doesn't work for this case. I have implemented as below:

```
if(!AppUtils.isValidEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString())){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter valid email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
}
```

my function to validate:

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
      return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();

}
```

is there a regex or some other way to allow special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do use the basic regex pattern and tweak it according to your needs. To your specific problem, allowing special character in Email.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.+[a-z._-]+$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
return matcher.matches();
```

Or you can also tweak the regex which is being used in [EMAIL_ADDRESS of Pattern](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/81aa097/core/java/android/util/Patterns.java)

Just append the special characters you need like `\\\&`

```
public static final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS
    = Pattern.compile(
        "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
        "\\@" +
        "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
        "(" +
            "\\." +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
        ")+"
    );
```

Comment: Yes this worked. Thanks for help Vikalp but I really don't know how to tweak this regular expressions.